# Google search results showing my site even though I've disallowed it in robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

My staging site is showing up in search results, even though I've specified that I don't want the site crawled. Here's the contents of my robots.txt file for the staging site:

```
User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ISYS Web Spider 9)
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Google caches robots.txt for several days, sometimes up to a week, according to their site. You can't expect a change that you made today to be reflected immediately. Also, check Google's help page at http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2387297, especially the last section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your robots.txt tells Google not to crawl/index your page's content.

It doesn't tell Google not to *add* your URL to their search results.

So if your page (which is blocked by robots.txt) is linked somewhere else, and Google finds this link, it checks your robots.txt if it is allowed to crawl. It finds that it is forbidden, but hey, it still has your URL.

Now Google might decide that it would be useful to include this URL in their search index. But as they are not allowed (per your robots.txt) to get the page's metadata/content, they only index it with keywords from your URL itself, and possibly anchor/title text that someone else used to link to your page.

If you don't want your URLs to be indexed by Google, you'd need to use the `meta`-`robots`, e.g.:

```
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

See Google's documentation: [Using meta tags to block access to your site](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710)

Answer (score 1):

You're robots file looks clean, but remember Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc. etc. do not need to crawl your site in order to index it.

There is a very good chance the [Open Directory Project](http://www.dmoz.org/) or a less *polite* bot of some kind stumbled across it. Once someone else finds your site these days it seems everyone gets their hands on it. Drives me crazy too.

A good rule of thumb when staging is:

1. Always test your robots file for any oversights with relation to syntax before posting it on your production site. Try [robots.txt Checker](http://www.searchenginepromotionhelp.com/m/robots-text-tester/), [Analyze robots.txt](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/), or [Robots.txt Analysis - Check whether your site can be accessed by Robots](http://phpweby.com/services/robots).

2.Password protect your content while staging. Even if its somewhat bogus, put a login and password at your indexes root. Its an extra step for your fans and testers -- but well worth it if you want polite --OR-- unpolite bots out of your hair.

3.Depending on the project you may not want to use your actual domain for testing. Even if I have a static ip - sometimes Ill use [dnsdynamic](http://www.dnsdynamic.org/) or [noip.com](http://www.noip.com/) to stage my password protected site. So for example, if I want to stage my domain **ihatebots.com** :) I will simply go to dnsdynamic or noip (theyre free btw) and create a fake domain such as: **ihatebots.user32.com** or **somthingtotallyrandom.user32.com** and then assign my ip address to it. This way even if someone crawls my staging project -- my original domain: **ihatebots.com** is still untouched from any kind of search engine result (so are its records too btw).

Remember there are billions of dollars around the world aimed at finding you 24 hrs a day and that number is ever increasing. Its tough these days. Be creative and always password protect if you can while staging.

Good luck.